# How to handle the multiple attribute in 'emph' element

Tags: xml, xslt

`Input xml:
    <emph italic="yes" superscript="yes">nd</emph>`

```
My XSL Code:
<xsl:template match="emph[normalize-space()]">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="lower-case(@italic)='yes'">
            <italic>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </italic>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="lower-case(@superscript)='yes'">
            <sup>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </sup>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise/>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Output with my xsl code but i am not getting proper out according to below required outpu:
    `<italic>nd</italic>`

```
Required Output:
<italic><sup>nd</sup></italic>
```

Comment: I am still waiting...please give my answer

Comment: Check this code
<xsl:template match="emph[normalize-space()]">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="lower-case(@italic)='yes' and lower-case(@superscript)='yes'">
                <italic>
                <sup>
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </sup>
                </italic>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise/>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

Comment: ok. i do like that code, but i have one more question suppose i received <emph italic="yes">nd</emph> or <emoh superscript="yes">nd</emph> code. exiting code condition failed.

Comment: i have also like code in xml. <emph italic="yes">Abstract.</emph>, and <emph superscript="yes">2</emph>

Comment: okk.. thank you its working finee

Comment: Wow, you raise a question at 6:30am and you complain that it hasn't been answered by 6:50? Do you imagine we're all in the same timezone or something?

Answer (score 0):

XSLT 2.0 next-match is ideal for this:

```
<xsl:template match="emph" mode="render" priority="3">
  <italic>
    <xsl:next-match/>
  </italic>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[@superscript='yes']" mode="render" priority="2">
  <sup>
    <xsl:next-match/>
  </sup>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="render" priority="1">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

and of course you can add other rules for other attributes.